# Deploying Azure Function App in CI intermittently changes function key

Tags: azure, deployment, continuous-integration, azure-function-app

I'm using an Azure DevOps release pipeline to deploy an Azure function app using an ARM template with an **Azure resource group deployment** and **Azure App Service Deploy** tasks. The problem I have is the function access keys change intermittently, which, I'm assuming would only happen on its own when the function app gets deployed.

From what I've read, the only time the keys should change is if the function app gets deleted first, but this is not part of the deployment task group.

We use the same pipeline task group to deploy another function app and normally the function keys remain the same, but sometimes they change randomly for individual functions.

Does anyone have an idea what could be going on here or advise if there's a setting that could stop the keys from changing?

Comment: Did you find any answers to this?